# What is the minimum version of Microsoft Edge that can be used with adapter.js?

Tags: webrtc, ortc

I see on caniuse.com that [ortc](https://caniuse.com/#search=ortc) support was added in 14 and [webrtc](https://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc) in 15. But what is the minimum version that can be shimmed via adapter.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adapter.js shims based on ORTC so it will work with version 14. However, since 14 doesn't support the VP8 or H264 video codecs that support is limited to audio-only calls.